# adding/updating meta tags not working in angular5

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I used below code for adding or updating meta tags at runtime in angular5

```
import { Title ,Meta} from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
constructor( private meta:Meta)
 {
 this.meta.addTags([
            {name: 'description', content: 'How to use Angular 4 meta 
       service'},
            {name: 'author', content: 'talkingdotnet'},
            {name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Meta Service'}
          ]);
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Angular 4 meta service' 
 });
  }
```

imported meta service in appmodule

But it is not working(not in my page source).can anyone pls help me

Thanks

Comment: getting any error?

Comment: try adding this code in your root components .ts file

Comment: no error.but no updates in meta

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to just change :

```
this.meta.updateTag({ content: 'Angular 4 meta service'} , 'name="description"' );
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-meta-tag-updated)** (Instead of view page source check via inspect element) Reason is explained below

Your method is also working 100% fine , you can check that in my given demo.

---

> Angular is not served from server side , that's why you can see any
>   meta tags via page view source , any thing that is being changed after page loads that won't be shown in page view source
>
> If you want to check the updated meta tags you need to inspect element
>   and check there
>
> If you want to server side rendering then you can go for **[Angular Universal](https://universal.angular.io/)**

Comment: @kamalav , please check the updated answer , Hope that will clear all your doubts :)

Comment: thanks,I can see meta  while  inspect element.Why can't I see while giving view page source

Comment: can u pls explain why can't i see while viewing page source

Comment: @kamalav , please read notes , an also checkout Angular Universal , you will get the idea

Comment: In Angular Universal doesn't explain anything about meta tags. The meta tags appear in inspect Element but not in view page source.

Comment: Thanks good answer!

Answer (score 4):

Please try using this template

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta, MetaDefinition } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  public constructor(public meta: Meta, public pageTitle: Title) {
    pageTitle.setTitle("MySite.COM");
    const keywords: MetaDefinition = {
      name: "keywords",
      content: "angular2, java, javaEE, angular-universal"
    }
    const description: MetaDefinition = {
      name: "description",
      content: "This is a description"
    }
    this.meta.addTags([keywords, description]);
  }

  title = 'app';
}
```

Refer [url](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/issues/340) for more updates

Comment: it works, see the inspector inside head tag, you will see these meta on very bottom

Answer (score 1):

Just use `addTags`. `updateTags` is for existing tags.

With just addTags

```
this.meta.addTags([
  {name: 'description', content: 'How to use Angular 4 meta service'},
  {name: 'author', content: 'talkingdotnet'},
  {name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Meta Service'}
]);
```

You get the following:

[image]

Further with updateTag notice the description change:

this.meta.addTags([
  {name: 'description', content: 'How to use Angular 4 meta service'},
  {name: 'author', content: 'talkingdotnet'},
  {name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Meta Service'}
]);

this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Angular 4 meta service'});

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a security feature which will only show page content provided in index.html file. One way to view this is to inspect your code on same page. You will be able to see you meta tags and it's values.
Another solution is to use [Angular Universal](https://github.com/angular/universal) which is useful for SEO purpose. By using Angular universal you'll be able to see you page content in view source.

Comment: doesn't answer the question... actually advertising for some completely different thing...